# What is the relation between BRST quantization and gauge fixing quantization

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, string-theory, quantization

To quantize gauge field, one usually use gauge-fixing procedure and then plus ghost field, my question is what the relation between [BRST quantization](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Becchi-Rouet-Stora-Tyutin_symmetry) and gauge fixing quantization is? Because it seems the latter is a special case of the former. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget BV and BFV!

Comment: Roughly speaking you want to work with M/G one way is to make qoutient directly - gauge fixing; another way is to use RESOLUTION i.e. to find homological complex such that its say zero cohomology describe the quotient that is BRST, BV , Faddev-Popov ghosts....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Physics StackExchange and is introductory material in the field.

Comment: @ChrisGerig really? It's actually a serious mathematical issue. Urs Schreiber, for instance, is working to understand quantisation at a deep mathematical level, and how the various versions (deformation quantisation, geometric quantisation, and all the variants) relate.

Answer (score 7):

I do not think that it makes sense to say that the gauge-fixing is a special case of BRST quantization:

$\rightarrow$ The gauge-fixing procedure is actually a normalization technique and it is utilized in order to eliminate unphysical degrees of freedom (gauge directions) in the path integral quantization of the various gauge theories. This -rather naturally- destroys the gauge invariance. A standard method to restore the lost gauge invariance -and thus to recover the physics- is the [**Batalin-Vilkovisky (BV)**](https://mathoverflow.net/q/30352/85967) or  **antifield** formalism:
 $\rightarrow$ after introducing some extra fields in the theory (ghost fields and conjugate antifields), an extended action is constructed involving all these variables. This action is invariant under the [BRST](http://www.cbpf.br/~cosmogra/Escolas/5_Escola/V_ESCOLA_566_605.pdf) symmetry operator $s$ (usually called **BRST-differential**), which now replaces the original gauge symmetry. Its cohomology essentially contains the physics, in the following sense:
 $\rightarrow$ The BRST-differential is nilpotent $s^2=0$ and thus its cohomological groups $H^n(s)$ can be constructed. $H^0(s)$ consists of the gauge invariant functions (that is: the observables).

You can find more details in [these](https://saalburg.aei.mpg.de/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2017/03/henneaux.pdf) notes and the references therein.

**Edit:** The question: [What is the BRST-anti-BRST formalism?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/187183/85967) and the answer there, are also related and may be of some further help.